# pass image in request body in python

Tags: azure, rest, face-detection, azure-rest-api

Currently I am trying to work on face detection API provided by Azure. I am currently using Rest call to detect face in an image.
More details could be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/python

Below is the sample code for detecting face in an image:

```
import json, os, requests
subscription_key = os.environ['FACE_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY']
assert subscription_key

face_api_url = os.environ['FACE_ENDPOINT'] + '/face/v1.0/detect'

image_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-sample-data-files/master/ComputerVision/Images/faces.jpg'

headers = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key}

params = {
'detectionModel': 'detection_02',
'returnFaceId': 'true'
}

response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params,
                     headers=headers, json={"url": image_url})
print(json.dumps(response.json()))
```

Now what is want is instead of passing an image from github or any public URL, I want to pass image from my local machine. For ex an image is available on my local machine at "/home/ubuntu/index.png".

Any help on how can I do it would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess there are two ways to detect a face:
1. detect with URL
2. detect with stream

More details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/face/face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the Content-Type header of the POST request to "application/octet-stream" and add the image to the HTTP body:

```py
import os
import requests
import json

subscription_key = os.environ['FACE_SUBSCRIPTION_KEY']
face_api_url = os.environ['FACE_ENDPOINT'] + '/face/v1.0/detect'

headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream', 
           'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key }

with open('/home/ubuntu/index.png', 'rb') as img:
    res = requests.post(face_api_url , headers=headers, data=img)
    res.raise_for_status()
    faces = res.json()
    print(faces)
```

API reference: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236